# Installing Arch on VM - DNS Issues

Tags: arch-linux, dns

I have been following the Install Wiki and I have arrived at the part where I need to install X Server. My issue is that I cant install X because my DNS doesnt work. I can ping 8.8.8.8 just fine, google.com does not respond.

Running Arch as a VM through Hyper-V

```
# nano /etc/resolv.conf
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 8.8.4.4

# systemctl stop dhcpcd.service
#ip link
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noquene state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000 link/ether 00:15:5d:00:0f:03 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff

# ip link set eth0 up

# ip addr add 10.100.0.25/24 dev eth0

# ip route add default via 10.100.0.25
```

Where should I start in troubleshooting this? I dont mind working out the problem I just dont know what to do.

Comment: Check (with e.g. `tcpdump`) whether `10.100.0.25` forwards the UDP packets.

Comment: The issue appeared to be from a VPN tunnel coming from my router. Thanks for the info about tcpdump, it actually did help when troubleshooting the problem. Mark as Answer and Ill approve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check (with e.g. `tcpdump`) whether 10.100.0.25 forwards the UDP packets.

Comment: This definitely helped me solve my problem. tcpdump along with a multitude of other tcpip commands I found out that my DNS entries were being redirected to a VPN tunnel.

Comment: @JonH You could write your own answer describing in detail what you did.

Comment: I actually have been working on this off and on for almost a week and dont really remember how and what I actually did. I do know that when you mentioned tcpdump that it was that ability that was able for me to see that the packets were being sent to my router and then to a vpn tunnel.